# Rails: City-state gem "f.select" issue to getting data states from selected country

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi dear all rails community. I used city-state gem to making dropdown menu for countries and states. I have looked the [this tutorial](https://forum.upcase.com/t/dependent-country-city-state/7038) and [this github samples](https://github.com/pbmarcano/city-state-dropdown-test) . in sample codes, it was like belov;

```
 <div class="field">
  <!-- Country -->
  <%= f.label :country %>
  <%= selected_tag :country, options_for_select(CS.countries.map { |c| [c[1], c[0]] } ) %>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <!-- State -->
  <%= label_tag :state %>
  <%= selected_tag :state, options_for_select([]) %>
</div>
```

so i changed "selected_tag" names to "f.selected"

```
<div class="field">
      <!-- Country -->
      <%= f.label :country %>
      <%= f.select :country, options_for_select(CS.countries.map { |c| [c[1], c[0]] } ) %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <!-- State -->
      <%= label_tag :state %>
      <%= f.select :state, options_for_select([]) %>
    </div>
```

and it is not working now.

for the detail of problem: it was getting states from countries when you select any country. but it is not getting states now when i  change name from "selected_tag" to "f.select". It is is looking empty

can you check the links and tell me why is not working?

thanks.

Comment: Indents aside, they look the same to me? When you say 'not working', what does happen - any errors, or other behaviour?

Comment: opps sorry.  it was getting states from countries when you select any country. but it is not getting states now when i  change name from "selected_tag" to "f.select". It is is looking empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you change the fields from `select_tag` to `f.select` you're changing the html id and name of the select elements. `f.select` will generate an id and name prefixed by the model passed into the form. Your javascript will be looking for an ids like `country` and `state`. After changing the elements to use rails form builder `f.select` tags the ids will be something like `famous_person_country` and `famous_person_state`.

Check your html source in the browser (view source) to see what ids have been generated in your form for the select tags and update your `cities.js` javascript accordingly. It should look something like:

```
var country = document.getElementById("famous_person_country");
var state = document.getElementById("famous_person_state");
```

Hope this helps.